# How to create object from array elements to be passed into mongodb aggregation in mongoose and node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've a usecase in which I'll get dynamic field names in an array. I need to pass those fields to the mongo db aggregation query to get the sum of that field values in a given month. I need to remove the `timeStamp & deviceId` fields in array.

```js
let jsonObj = [
  { name: "heat", value: "HEAT" },
  { name: "humidity", value: "HUMIDITY" },
  { name: "deviceId", value: "DEVICEID" },
  { name: "timeStamp", value: "TIMESTAMP" }
];

let vList = [];
jsonObj.forEach(async data => {
  if (!data.name.match(/time/g) || !data.name.match(/deviceId/g)) {
    vList.push(data.name); //Should exclude timestamp & deviceId (case-insensitive)
  }
});

let variableObj = [];
vList.forEach(async data => {
  let k = "{" + '"$sum":"$' + data + '"}';
  // console.log(k)
  k = JSON.parse(k);
  variableObj.push(data + ":" + k);
});
```

Then resultant array looks like the following.

```
[ 'heat:{"$sum":"$heat"}',
  'humidity:{"$sum":"$humidity"}',
  'timeStamp:{"$sum":"$timeStamp"}',
  'deviceId:{"$sum":"$deviceId"}' ]
```

Am not getting how to remove the single quotes around each item and how to pass them to query.

My query is:

```js
db.collection(templateId).aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      entryDayTime: {
        $lt: new Date(lastDay),
        $gte: new Date(firstDay)
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$deviceId",
      Count: { $sum: 1 }
      // Should pass those array elements here like,
      //heat:{"$sum":"$heat"},
      //humidity:{"$sum":"$humidity"}
    }
  },
  { $sort: { entryDayTime: -1 } }
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create the whole group object together and pass it onto the `$group` stage. Also remove those `async` keywords, the iterations are not asynchronous.

**Note:** The if clause should have `&&` to exclude both keywords and `i` flag is for case-insensitivity in regex. And creation of the target object can be completed in the first iteration itself.

```js
let jsonObj = [
  { name: "heat", value: "HEAT" },
  { name: "humidity", value: "HUMIDITY" },
  { name: "deviceId", value: "DEVICEID" },
  { name: "timeStamp", value: "TIMESTAMP" }
];

let groupObject = {
  _id: "$deviceId",
  Count: { $sum: 1 }
};

jsonObj.forEach(data => {
  if (!data.name.match(/timestamp/gi) && !data.name.match(/deviceid/gi)) {
    groupObject[data.name] = { $sum: "$" + data.name };
  }
});

console.log(groupObject);
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```js
const jsonObj = [
  { name: "heat", value: "HEAT" },
  { name: "humidity", value: "HUMIDITY" },
  { name: "deviceId", value: "DEVICEID" },
  { name: "timeStamp", value: "TIMESTAMP" }
];

const filteredJson = jsonObj.filter(i => i.name !== "deviceId" && i.name !== "timeStamp");

const groupQuery = {
  $group:{
     _id:"$deviceId",
     Count:{$sum:1}
  }
};

filteredJson.forEach(row => {
  groupQuery.$group[row.name] = {"$sum": `$${row.name}`};
});

console.log(groupQuery);
```

Hope this helps. All you need to do is now, insert the $group with the variable prepared above.